# camera for a hexagonal grid

Tags: c#, camera

I am trying to make a game. It will be in the 4x game style. I have an hexagonal grid. I want to use that as the board, playing map, where each hexagon is a position.

An hexagon can have units on it, planets or nothing. But the problem I am having is how to make a camera that can scroll over the map. I have never done such a thing and I can't find anything. Most things point me to XNA.

I am hoping someone can tell me the principle in big lines or refer me to some links with guides or explanations.

Comment: This question will probably get closed for being to broad. It's hard to give a definite answer to it, but look at XNA, MonoGame and Unity. They're all C# based frameworks that make it easier to write games (easier because writing a game is never easy). If you have specific problems that aren't answered by the multitude of tutorials online come and ask here or more appropriately at gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if you have a grid of which you only want to draw a portion, I would implement a camera by storing an offset into the grid, and the start drawing at that offset. If you want to scroll 1 tile at a time, you can store a tile offset, which is easy. If you want to scroll to individual pixel positions, then store a pixel offset, and calculate what the first tile you need to draw is from that.

```
for(int y = yPixelOffset / tileHeight; y < displayHeight; y++) {
    for(int x = xPixelOffset / tileWidth; x < displayWidth; x++) {
        // draw tile[x,y] at (displayLeft + x * tileWidth - xPixelOffset,
        //    displayTop + y * tileHeight - yPixelOffset)
    }
}
```

I don't usually deal with hexagonal grids, but I think that just involves offsetting each second row by half a tile width.